# Show dialog over textformfield not in center

Tags: flutter, dropdown, showdialog, customdialog, textformfield

[image: I am trying to get the output like below image.]

I am trying to show the dialog when user click on texform filed but it is showing in the center of the screen not on textformfield ? please help me..

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DropDownButton` instead of dialog to achieve your aim
[enter link description here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply, DropDownButton replaces the TextFormField is good idea. but in my case when user clicks on textformfiled i want to show list of items.. just like image shown above.

Comment: As long as the user will not type manually, this means that you do not need to TextFormField in this case

Comment: yes, user does not type manually. he has to select from list so which widget is use.

Comment: according to @faroukosama answer you don't need TextFormFiled  here and you can use custom widget. then you can use dropDownButton Value

Comment: You're welcome my friend. I hope it solves your problem

Comment: finally i got the required output by using overlay widget.. https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9

Comment: Good. Thanks for share your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeAheadFormField package to use the text field as text field as well as dropdown. Please find sample example code

```
 TypeAheadFormField(
      textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
        controller: textFieldController,  
        autofocus: false,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        onSelection: (selectedItem) {
      print(selectedItem);
    },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          fillColor: Color(0xFFEAEAEA),
          filled: true,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
       ),
      ),   
      keepSuggestionsOnLoading: false,
      suggestionsCallback: (pattern) => getSuggestions(searchList, pattern),
      itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) => ListTile(
        title: Text(suggestion),
      ),
      transitionBuilder: (context, suggestionsBox, controller) =>
          suggestionsBox,
      onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
        if (onSelection != null) {
          onSelection(suggestion);
        }
        textFieldController.text = suggestion;
      },
      getImmediateSuggestions: true,
    )
List<String> getSuggestions(List<String>  searchList, String query) {
final filtered = searchList
    .where((item) => item.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()));
return filtered.toList();}
```

where searchList is list to be displayed on textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i think it's help for you!

```
class _YourPageState extends State<YourPage> {
  Map yourJson = {
    "status": true,
    "message": "success",
    "data": {
      "list": [
        {"idattribute": "2", "attrName": "BBQ"},
        {"idattribute": "1", "attrName": "FRUIT JUICE"}
      ]
    }
  };
  int _value = 1;
  List<DropdownMenuItem<int>> _menuItems;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    List dataList = yourJson["data"]["list"];
    _menuItems = List.generate(
      dataList.length,
          (i) => DropdownMenuItem(
        value: int.parse(dataList[i]["idattribute"]),
        child: Text("${dataList[i]["attrName"]}"),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton<int>(
          items: _menuItems,
          value: _value,
          onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _value = value),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```